# How to add nested child nodes to a parent node in xml documents using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have two xml files snapshot.

**Input xml**:

[image: input_xml]

**Desired Output XML**:

[image: output_xml]

I need to add few child nodes to the parent node with tag `<triggers\>` using python script.

The example of child nodes to add is highlighted in grey in output.xml snapshot.

Complete tag to replace `triggers` node.

```
  <triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
      <spec>1 1 1 1 1</spec>
    </hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
  </triggers>
```

Can anyone help me with the python script for replacing the non-empty tag whenever encountered with above tag using python script?

Comment: Can you provide some example input/code and not an image?

Comment: [You should not post code or sample data as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#285557)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Parfait. I will keep the points in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ET.SubElement` to create subelements to a given node. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents).

Then you can set `.text` to be the value of that node.

For example, consider the following input xml document:

```
<root>
  <triggers/>
  <triggers/>
</root>
```

Try this:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

#Get all triggers elements
trigger_elements = root.findall('./triggers')

#For each trigger element in your xml document
for trigger in trigger_elements:

    #Make subelement to the initial trigger element
    time_trigger_element = ET.SubElement(trigger, 'hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger')

    #Make subelement to the time trigger elemenent with name 'spec'
    spec_element = ET.SubElement(time_trigger_element, 'spec')

    #Set the text of spec element to 1 1 1 1 1
    spec_element.text = ' '.join(['1']*5)


#Save the xml tree to a file
tree.write("output.xml")
```

Outputs:

```
<root>
  <triggers><hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger><spec>1 1 1 1 1</spec></hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger></triggers>
  <triggers><hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger><spec>1 1 1 1 1</spec></hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger></triggers>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with BeautifulSoup, you can try something like this:

```
code1 = """   
<triggers/>
"""
code2 = """    
<triggers>
    <hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
      <spec>1 1 1 1 1</spec>
    </hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger>
  </triggers>

"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup1 = bs(code1)
soup2 = bs(code2)

old = soup1.find('triggers')
new = soup2.find('triggers')
old.replaceWith(new)
print(soup1)
```