# How can I add child node to parent node in xml using Python?

Tags: python

I have XML where I have to add a child node to the parent node using python.
I have the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><PLMRequest><StyleNumber>20SM1401</StyleNumber><StyleName>PG001 Style</StyleName><Theme>Ocean</Theme><ProductSpecialist>Ashok Gangisetty</ProductSpecialist><Color><ColorCode>0816</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0044</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1>INF</UserDefinedField1><UserDefinedField2>TH02</UserDefinedField2></Color><Color><ColorCode>0461</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0430</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0646</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1>INN</UserDefinedField1><UserDefinedField2>TH02</UserDefinedField2></Color><Color><ColorCode>C801</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>C750</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0110</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>SK</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>KS</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color></PLMRequest>
```

I want output like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><PLMRequest><Overview><StyleNumber>20SM1401</StyleNumber><StyleName>PG001 Style</StyleName><Theme>Ocean</Theme><ProductSpecialist>Ashok Gangisetty</ProductSpecialist></Overview><ColorInfo><Color><ColorCode>0816</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0044</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1>INF</UserDefinedField1><UserDefinedField2>TH02</UserDefinedField2></Color><Color><ColorCode>0461</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0430</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0646</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1>INN</UserDefinedField1><UserDefinedField2>TH02</UserDefinedField2></Color><Color><ColorCode>C801</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>C750</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>0110</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>SK</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color><Color><ColorCode>KS</ColorCode><UserDefinedField1/><UserDefinedField1/></Color></ColorInfo></PLMRequest>
```

Python code i have used to convert Json to XML

```
import json
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree import cElementTree
import ast
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import xmltodict
import xml.dom.minidom
import xml.etree.ElementTree as DT
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.__dict__ = json.loads(data)
styleobj =Test(APIsInputData)
styleDto = styleobj.value[0]
root = ET.Element('PLMRequest')
ET.SubElement(root,"StyleNumber").text = styleDto["StyleCode"]
ET.SubElement(root,"StyleName").text = styleDto["Name"]
ET.SubElement(root,"Theme").text = styleDto["Theme"]["Name"]
ET.SubElement(root,"ProductSpecialist").text = styleDto["ProdSpecialist"]["Name"]
for color in styleDto["StyleColorways"]:
    StyleColorways = ET.SubElement(root,"Color")
    ET.SubElement(StyleColorways,"ColorCode").text = color["Code"]
    if color["UserDefinedOne"] is None:
        ET.SubElement(StyleColorways,"UserDefinedField1").text = color["UserDefinedOne"]
    else:
        ET.SubElement(StyleColorways,"UserDefinedField1").text = color["UserDefinedOne"]["Code"]
    if color["UserDefinedTwo"] is None:
        ET.SubElement(StyleColorways,"UserDefinedField1").text = color["UserDefinedOne"]
    else:
        ET.SubElement(StyleColorways,"UserDefinedField2").text = color["UserDefinedTwo"]["Code"]
tree_out = ET.tostring(root, encoding="UTF-8")
newXML = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(tree_out.decode('UTF-8'))
pretty_xml = newXML.toprettyxml()
Outputvalue = pretty_xml
```

Json file I used

```
{"@odata.context":"https://prd-euc1.fplm.eu1.inforcloudsuite.com/api/odata/$metadata#STYLE","value":[{"@odata.etag":"W/\"YmluYXJ5J0FBQUFBQUg0RzFNPSc=\"","StyleId":1238,"StyleCode":"20SM1401","Name":"PG001 Style","IsDeleted":0,"StyleColorways":[{"StyleColorwayId":766,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"0816","Name":"Saffron","Description":"Saffron"},{"StyleColorwayId":767,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"0044","Name":"Swan White","Description":"Swan White","UserDefinedOne":{"Id":1,"Code":"INF","Name":"In For","ModifyId":1,"ModifyDate":"2018-07-16T08:54:12.803Z"},"UserDefinedTwo":{"Id":2,"Code":"TH02","Name":"Theme 02","ModifyId":1,"ModifyDate":"2018-07-16T08:55:59.073Z"}},{"StyleColorwayId":768,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"0461","Name":"Pastel Blue","Description":"Pastel Blue"},{"StyleColorwayId":769,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"0430","Name":"Sport Blue","Description":"Sport Blue"},{"StyleColorwayId":770,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"0646","Name":"Light Rose Water ","Description":"Light Rose Water ","UserDefinedOne":{"Id":2,"Code":"INN","Name":"In Next","ModifyId":1,"ModifyDate":"2018-07-16T08:54:39.96Z"},"UserDefinedTwo":{"Id":2,"Code":"TH02","Name":"Theme 02","ModifyId":1,"ModifyDate":"2018-07-16T08:55:59.073Z"}},{"StyleColorwayId":771,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"C801","Name":"Shocking Orange / Navy Blue","Description":"High Visibility Shocking Orange / Navy Blue"},{"StyleColorwayId":772,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"C750","Name":"Flame Red / Black","Description":"High Visibility Flame Red / Black"},{"StyleColorwayId":773,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"0110","Name":"Silver","Description":""},{"StyleColorwayId":781,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"SK","Name":"SK01","Description":""},{"StyleColorwayId":782,"StyleId":1238,"Code":"KS","Name":"KS01","Description":""}],"Theme":{"Id":10,"Code":"OCEAN","Name":"Ocean","ModifyId":1,"ModifyDate":"2020-02-11T10:53:32.333Z"},"ProdSpecialist":{"UserId":34,"UserGuid":"5c302bc2-616e-4943-9baf-323feecfd65c","UserName":"Ashok.Gangisetty@infor.com","Name":"Ashok Gangisetty","IsActivated":false}}]}
```

Comment: Please figure out how to make a minimal example. XML you provided is too long.

Comment: Where's your Python code?  And which XML library are you using?

Comment: Please format your code properly. Nobody's going to read that. And add a **significantly** smaller JSON as your example.

Comment: I have changed my Code and Jaosn

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add nested child nodes to a parent node in xml documents using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657430/how-to-add-nested-child-nodes-to-a-parent-node-in-xml-documents-using-python)

Comment: I already checked. but it's not worked.

Comment: I am using the xmltodict XML library.